# How to override a component in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

In my exercise, I need to insert some data into the database. And, I need to override the `com_users/models/registration.php` to do so. How can I do that so that I can play with database from `registration.php`? The main theme is that I cannot modify the core files of `joomla`.

Comment: ***Core files are not meant to modify and should never be!*** Create a module and use that, to work with the DB.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla specific implementation details and not programming as defined of StackOverflow, it would be better asked on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

You already mentioned you have to work with `com_users`.

In any case **Joomla core file modification is not a recommended practice**. In your case working with `user` section  Joomla already provide a bundle of User events for custom DB actions and other extended features all these you can achieve with **Joomla Plugins**.

checkout the `Joomla profile plugin` , Also [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) it has all the basic User related events you can write your own custom plugin for joomla based on these events and achieve your requirement.

The question refer for the [Joomla component Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core).

Hope it make sense.